# Stored Procedure return unwanted cursor result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, cursors, memory-optimized-tables

### Context

I have created a stored procedure that simulates a merge command for an OLTP in-memory table. It used the simulated merge for upsert moving massive data form a normal table to an OLTP one.

### Procedure

This is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cache].[MoveInverterData] (@sourecInverterID bigint, @from datetime2(7))
AS   
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1; 
    DECLARE @InverterID bigint, @Timestamp datetime2(7), @Status nvarchar(50);

    DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
        SELECT [InverterID],[Timestamp],[Status]
        FROM [data].[InverterData]
        WHERE [InverterID] = @sourecInverterID AND [Timestamp] >= @from;  

    OPEN Employee_Cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor; 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status;

        UPDATE [cache].[InverterData]
        SET [Status] = @Status
        WHERE [InverterID] = @InverterID AND [Timestamp] = @Timestamp;  

        -- if there was no row to update, insert
        IF @@ROWCOUNT=0  
            INSERT INTO [cache].[InverterData]
                ([InverterID],[Timestamp],[Status])
            VALUES
                (@InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status);  
    END
      
    CLOSE Employee_Cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;

    RETURN(0)
END
```

The cursor upserts a range of rows like this because OLTP tables (target) [do not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/implementing-merge-functionality-in-a-natively-compiled-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) `MERGE` commands.

### Problem

If I execute my SP I will get a result the first cursor selected `FETCH` and a list of single row counts.

[image: table result]

[image: message]

### Question

I understand that this is normal behavior, but I try to suppress this to get a simpler result.

What I want:

1. No table result from `CURSOR` select
2. A sum of affected row count as single number of all update/insert operations

The empty `FETCH` was indeed an error and solves the `ROW` result problem (point 1).

Looks like this now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cache].[MoveInverterData] (@sourecInverterID bigint, @from datetime2(7))
AS   
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @i INT = 1; 
    DECLARE @InverterID bigint, @Timestamp datetime2(7), @Status nvarchar(50);

    DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
        SELECT [InverterID],[Timestamp],[Status]
        FROM [data].[InverterData]
        WHERE [InverterID] = @sourecInverterID AND [Timestamp] >= @from;  

    OPEN Employee_Cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [cache].[InverterData]
        SET [Status] = @Status
        WHERE [InverterID] = @InverterID AND [Timestamp] = @Timestamp;  

        -- if there was no row to update, insert
        IF @@ROWCOUNT=0  
            INSERT INTO [cache].[InverterData]
                ([InverterID],[Timestamp],[Status])
            VALUES
                (@InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status); 

        FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor INTO @InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status;
    END
      
    CLOSE Employee_Cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor;

    RETURN(0)
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a cursor*, write the update and insert operations explicitly as set-based operations:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE cache.MoveInverterData
(
    @sourceInverterID bigint, 
    @from datetime2(7)
)
AS   
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RowsAffected integer = 0;

    -- TODO: Add error handling

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        -- Update existing rows
        UPDATE CID
        SET [Status] = DID.[Status]
        FROM [data].InverterData AS DID
        JOIN cache.InverterData AS CID
                WITH (SNAPSHOT)
            ON CID.InverterID = DID.InverterID
            AND CID.[Timestamp] = DID.[Timestamp]
        WHERE
            DID.InverterID = @sourceInverterID
            AND DID.[Timestamp] >= @from;

        SET @RowsAffected += @@ROWCOUNT;

        -- Insert new rows
        INSERT cache.InverterData
            (InverterID, [Timestamp], [Status])
        SELECT
            DID.InverterID,
            DID.[Timestamp],
            DID.[Status]
        FROM [data].InverterData AS DID
        WHERE
            DID.InverterID = @sourceInverterID
            AND DID.[Timestamp] >= @from
            AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM cache.InverterData AS CID
                    WITH (SNAPSHOT)
                WHERE
                    CID.InverterID = DID.InverterID
                    AND CID.[Timestamp] = DID.[Timestamp]
            );

        SET @RowsAffected += @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    -- TODO: Use the @RowsAffected result
END;
```

Ensure both tables have a (non-hash) index on `InverterID, [Timestamp]`.

* Unlike some other database engines, cursors are usually quite inefficient in SQL Server. The overhead and per-row operations almost always make a set-based solution faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you wish to use a natively-compiled stored procedure as much as possible, create a memory-optimized table type to hold the new data:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.InverterData AS TABLE
(
    RowID integer IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    InverterID  bigint NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
    [Status] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH (RowID)
        WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1024)
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);
```

Then write a natively-compiled procedure to merge the new data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cache.MoveInverterData_Native
    @InverterData dbo.InverterData READONLY
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN ATOMIC WITH (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english')

    DECLARE @RowID integer = 1; 
    DECLARE @InverterID bigint, @Timestamp datetime2(7), @Status nvarchar(50);

    WHILE @RowID > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @InverterID = ID.InverterID,
            @Timestamp = ID.[Timestamp],
            @Status = ID.[Status]
        FROM @InverterData AS ID
        WHERE ID.RowID = @RowID;

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @RowID = 0
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE cache.InverterData
            SET [Status] = @Status
            WHERE InverterID = @InverterID
            AND [Timestamp] = @Timestamp;

            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                INSERT cache.InverterData
                    (InverterID, [Timestamp], [Status])
                VALUES
                    (@InverterID, @Timestamp, @Status);

            SET @RowID += 1;
        END;
    END;
END;
```

And a wrapper procedure to populate the memory-optimized table type from the source table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE cache.MoveInverterData
(
    @sourceInverterID bigint, 
    @from datetime2(7)
)
AS   
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @InverterData dbo.InverterData;

    INSERT @InverterData
        (InverterID, [Timestamp], [Status])
    SELECT
        ID.InverterID,
        ID.[Timestamp],
        ID.[Status]
    FROM [data].InverterData AS ID
    WHERE
        ID.InverterID = @sourceInverterID
        AND ID.[Timestamp] >= @from;

    EXECUTE cache.MoveInverterData_Native @InverterData;
END;
```

The whole process is then invoked by a single call like:

```
EXECUTE cache.MoveInverterData
    @sourceInverterID = 1,
    @from = '20180601';
```